# how to delete elements with click on window with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want (setting - content) to be closed every time the user clicks on any part of the window except setting - content.
but not work this code: (document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e){....})and signals an error.
How can I do this correctly?

```js
var icon = document.getElementsByClassName("setting--icon");
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('setting--content');
for (var i = 0; i < icon.length; i++) {
   icon[i].onclick = function(){
    var setClasses = !this.classList.contains('active');
        setClass(icon, 'active', 'remove');
        setClass(panel, 'active', 'remove');
        if (setClasses) {
         this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("active");
       }
   }
}

function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
 for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
   els[i].classList[fnName](className);
 }
}

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e){
   if (!(event.target == 'setting--content')) {                 panel.classList.remove('active');
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("active");
  }
})
```

```css
.setting--icon{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}


.setting--content {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: -150%;
    width: 50%;
    height:20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 2rem;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border:1px solid green;
}

.setting--content.active {
    top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<form >
  <div class="setting--icon">1</div> 
  <div class="setting--content">
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="search …">
  </div>
</form>

<div>
  <div class="setting--icon">2</div>
  <div class="setting--content"> 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus explicabo repellendus quos illo eaque vitae, nostrum id accusantium. Cum est fugiat animi molestiae dicta praesentium repellat ipsa iusto dolore perspiciatis?     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To check which element has clicked, you can use `matches` method on `HTMLElement`, in your body click handler you can use it like this:

```
event.target.matches('.setting--content');
```

In your snippet, you are toggling the `.setting--content` by clicking on `.setting--icon`, so you should check that target is not `.setting--icon` like this:

```
event.target.matches('.setting--icon');
```

in order to above checkings, you should also check that clicked item is not in the `.setting--content`, you can do it by storing the current active panel in a variable and by using of `contains` method, check that clicked item is part of the `.setting--content` or not. like this:

```js
var icon = document.getElementsByClassName("setting--icon");
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('setting--content');
var activePanel = null;
for (var i = 0; i < icon.length; i++) {
  icon[i].onclick = function() {
    var setClasses = !this.classList.contains('active');
    setClass(icon, 'active', 'remove');
    setClass(panel, 'active', 'remove');
    if (setClasses) {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      activePanel = this.nextElementSibling;
      activePanel.classList.toggle("active");
    }
  }
}

function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].classList[fnName](className);
  }
}

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.setting--content') &&
    !event.target.matches('.setting--icon') &&
    activePanel && !activePanel.contains(event.target)) {
    setClass(panel, 'active', 'remove');
    setClass(icon, 'active', 'remove');
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.setting--icon {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.setting--content {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: -200%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 2rem;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.setting--content.active {
  top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="setting--icon">1</div>
  <div class="setting--content">
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="search …">
  </div>
</form>

<div>
  <div class="setting--icon">2</div>
  <div class="setting--content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus explicabo repellendus quos illo eaque vitae, nostrum id accusantium. Cum est fugiat animi molestiae dicta praesentium repellat ipsa iusto dolore perspiciatis? </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

BTW, since your `.setting--content` has `fixed` display, in below example I added style `body{ min-height: 100vh; }` in order to prevent `body` collapssed. and also I changed `top` property on `.setting--content` from `-150%` to `-200%` to run snippet correctly in preview mode.